# How to slice string on substrings that contain n characters c#?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

The function gets a string of numbers (e.g. "23559009") and the length of substrings value (e.g. 2), I need to implement the function so that it will slice the string of numbers by the value (e.g. "23", "35", "55", "59", "90", "00", "09") AND will return this data as array.

For now I have initial code for tests:

```
using System;

public static class Series
{
    public static string[] Slices(string numbers, int sliceLength)
    {
        int digits = numbers.Length;

        if(digits != null || digits > sliceLength || sliceLength < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        else 
            {
                string[] dgts = {"1", "2"};
                return dgts;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the `String` has some method allowing you to extract a Substring from it... ;-)

Comment: just a tip- you are validating the arguments and firing an ArgumentException- that's correct, but there's no need to actually use 'else' block. If it doesn't fire exception it would always proceed further, therefore using else in this situation is redundant.

Comment: I agree, else block is ugly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
public static string[] Slices(string numbers, int sliceLength) =>
    Enumerable.Range(0, numbers.Length - sliceLength + 1).
               Select(i => numbers.Substring(i, sliceLength)).
               ToArray();
```

Note that the single character last entry will be ignored + you may want to validate the parameters (`numbers` not null and `sliceLength` > 0).

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kpXP8x)

Comment: @elgonzo Doh, Sunday evening... it's actually `Enumerable.Range(0, numbers.Length - sliceLength + 1)`

Comment: @elgonzo Don't worry, Monday's coming ;)

Comment: That's exactly the reason of why i don't drink all the coffee today, but keep something for tomorrow. I am sure i will need plenty of it ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Did you measure the performances? I have the strong impression that this is slower than a normal loop

Comment: @Steve, why would it matter whether it is slower or faster by a fraction of a millisecond?

Comment: It depends on the context

Comment: @Steve, my apologies, i deleted that comment already. I was first relating your comment to the question, and thus got confused by it. It took some time for my brain to realize that your comment was rather discussing the code in this answer here unrelated to OP's probable usage scenario.

Comment: I have tested this one against mine and barring any errors on my side I find my answer slightly faster on a 20000 length string with 1000 loops. But definitively there is not enough difference between the two approaches to choose a winner.

Comment: You can remove the Note now, it is not relevant to the current version of the code. But removing the argument check was not ideal, as now Slices("0", 2) returns empty array, but Slices("0", 3) throws exception, which is kind of inconsistent behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

substring code for this will have major redundancy. send the string to a char array, then do a loop

```
char[] charray = inputstring.toCharArray();

List<string> deuces= new List<string>();
for(int i=0;i<charray.length;i++){
string holder = charray[i]+charray[i+1];
deuces.Add(holder)


}
```

keep in mind this is pseudo, everything you need is here, you will just have to create the variables, and make sure syntax is correct.

in the line :  for(int i=0;i

the two represents the value you want to slice by,

in the line : string holder = charray[i]+charray[i+1];
 you will need to add another char, for the amount of your split. i.e 3 would be:

string holder = charray[i].toString()+charray[i+1].toString+charray[i+2];

keep in mind if your split value ( in your case two) changes regularly you can nest another for loop

Comment: `string holder = charray[i]+charray[i+1];` What? o.O? Suggestion: Try the code of your answer in [dotnetfiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net)

Comment: Incorrect. OP asks to take 2 chars but not to advance for two char at each loop

Comment: if string is odd you will have to acocunt for null. and not incorrect, op wants an array of '2' character substrings parsed out of his input,  so "23559009" becomes "23", "35", "55", "59", "90", "00", "09"

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your evaluation of incorrect inputs, then getting your result in using normal for  loop isn't difficult

```
public string[] Slices(string numbers, int sliceLength)
{
    int digits = numbers.Length;
    string[] result = new string[numbers.Length + 1 - sliceLength];
    if (digits < sliceLength || sliceLength < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    else
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < numbers.Length + 1 - sliceLength; x++)
            result[x] = numbers.Substring(x, sliceLength);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not use sliceLength parameter, so it is not generally correct. And speaking about performance, why do you create list, potentially autoresize it few times and finally copy to array, when you can create array at the beginning directly?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek tested against a 20000 length string in a 1000 loop. It is slightly faster this one than the linq one. Nothing very important though.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek tried also with your array suggestion and now we have something. The version with the array declared is a lot faster than the one with the list or the linq ones

Comment: Ok. But now there is a bug in the loop test, the condition should contain sliceLength too.

Comment: yep, there is a bug. Total tests: 10. Passed: 6. Failed: 4. Skipped: 0.

Comment: Not sure what kind of tests are not passed. If you send to the Slices function a string of just 1 char or a string with less chars than the size of the slice, then the function throws an exception as original coded by the OP

Comment: so tests are failed at this points: SeriesTest.Slices_of_a_long_series ("918493904243"), SeriesTest.Slices_of_one_from_one ( "1"), SeriesTest.Slices_can_include_duplicates ("777777"), SeriesTest.Slices_of_one_from_two("12")

Comment: Hopefully now is fixed